# Proxy pattern implementation in smalltalk

Tags: design-patterns, smalltalk

I was reading Proxy pattern implementation in smalltalk where it is implemented using doesNotUnderstand.
I did not get it when will this method be invoked as in the scenario. Can some one give me a example/scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doesNotUnderstand:` or DNU gets invoked instead of the original message if the method lookup fails. The following example,

```
nil aSelectorThatDoesNotExist
```

triggers the default DNU on Object, which will raise a `MessageNotUnderstood` exception.

You can easily delegate message sends to another object using the `doesNotUnderstand:` protocol. For instance if I add the following method on my `Proxy`,

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    ^ target perform: aMessage selector withArguments: aMessage arguments
```

it will forward all messages that are not implemented on the `Proxy` itself to another `target` object. Important here is that the `Proxy` object should implement as few methods as possible, otherwise they can not be forwarded. For this reason [Pharo](http://pharo.org) or [Squeak](http://squeak.org) have a `ProtoObject` which only implements a basic set of methods. Typically a proxy inherits from `ProtoObject`.

Comment: Maybe a comment on how/why `#doesNotUnderstand:` gets invoked might be useful.

Comment: @dh82 thanks for the explanation. Is perform something like you pass it the selector and arguments and it executes the selector @ run time . Can you tell me why and when do we use perform.

Comment: @Jiten: you have it right. It's just like Ruby's `Object#send` method. You need it whenever you don't know what message to send until runtime. Ideally, you'd use it as little as you can, because it makes code very hard to understand: the senders-of/implementors-of tools become much less useful.

Comment: @FrankShearar : in this case we every time use a proxy object but if proxy and real subject are inherited from the same subject then how can  it be possible that the proxy does not have some methods (Real subject and proxy wil have same set of methods right)? and so its doesNotUnderstand is called.

Comment: If the proxy inherits from the subject's superclass, and the superclass defines all the methods, then you won't get a DNU, for sure. But in that case you're writing by hand what DNU gives you for free (at the cost of losing the explicit contract).

Answer (score 0):

More basically, "perform" is like Lisp "apply".(apply aFunction anArgumentList)

aFunction and anArgumentList being expressions to be evaluated.

**Example:**

> (apply (car '(* +)) '(2 3 4))
>   = 24
>
> (apply (cadr '(* +)) '(2 3 4))
>   = 9

It makes it possible to achieve calculated function calls, (and by extension calculated message sending).